# Tutorials for learning more about Jewish practice

Tags: hebrew, product-recommendation, torah-study, baal-teshuva

I wish to learn more about the steps for "Hazara betshova" (Getting stronger) preferably in Hebrew.
I have no knowledge of the Jewish practice at all so a place which assumes no past knowledge will be best.

Answer (score 3):

Check out these sites:

http://www.ohr.edu

http://www.aish.com

http://www.simpletoremember.com

http://www.beingjewish.com